# Generate web service interface from SOAP message (without WSDL)?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, soap

Is there any way to generate a web service interface using a SOAP message without a WSDL being provided?

Comment: Which framework do you use ? Wcf or old webservices ? In Wcf, you can share contracts (Service and Data contract) and create a proxy from it.

Comment: I need the server interface, not the client. All I have is a sample SOAP message.

Comment: @alimbada: Sounds strange. That is not a way Web services are defined. You can reverse engineer SOAP messages and create working service but it is a lot of work to do (and you have to understand it pretty well). How did you get messages? How is it possible that messages exist and web service description doesn't?

Comment: A third party payment system has some "callback" functionality which basically just posts SOAP messages to their users. They haven't supplied a WSDL, just sample messages and they want their users to implement the service.

Comment: @alimbada: make them give you the WSDL. I have found lack of the correct WSDL to be a problem in communication - and if not corrected, a problem in *communicating* - with a third party.

Comment: John: we're currently chasing them for a WSDL; hopefully they have one or can procure one. Otherwise, we've no choice but to reverse engineer it...

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of that kind of reverse engineering tool, but if the SOAP message is simple enough you should be able to create the service interface quite easily with a little bit of trial and error.

Comment: -1: bad idea. What if there's an "error" in handling payments?

Comment: @John Saunders: you could have noticed the comment about the payment system is more recent than my answer ;)